# NSSortDescriptor for A <-->> B <-->> C relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to initialize a NSFetchedResultsController.

In the data model I have 3 entities related to each other like this:

```
A <-->> B <-->> C
```

Entity 'A' has a property 'name' and entity 'C' has property 'someDate'.

I want to get all managedObjects belonging to entity 'A', sorted in
below order, when I fire a fetch request against it:

1. 'someDate' == today's date (AND) ascending order by name
2. ascending order by name

ie. first it should enlist the objects in 'A'  for which 'someDate' in
'C' is today's date, this list should be further sorted by 'name',
then it should enlist remaining objects in 'A' (for which 'someDate'
!= today's date) sorted by 'name'

Please suggest how can I achieve it in a single fetch request.

Comment: Dis you try anything already?

Comment: yeah.. implementing secound point is easy I can simply use.. NSSortDescriptor and provide 'name' as key..

Comment: Now implementing both the points simultaneously in a single fetch request is tricky.. I tried to use + sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector: and passing b.c.someDate as key but it is not working :(

Comment: You'll need at least 2 sort descriptors, but having part sorted primarily on date and half sorted primarily on name will be extremely difficult to do in the fetch request...

Comment: okay.. can you suggest me if I want to sort it only by date, then considering transitive relationship which is there.. is it possible to sort using key value path like this: b.c.someDate? If not then what is the other option for me?

Comment: `NSSortDescriptor` allows you to use a key path, yes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33267/discussion-between-miraaj-and-wain)